# RE : Unable to match session ID

Tags: regex

I have a session ID as `[0a7b2b7f-9a8f-4be5-9696-98d4b2d543f0]` and I am trying to match it with pattern as `[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z-0-9]{12}` in **notepad++** but I couldn't find the session ID.

And I tried with

`[[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z-0-9]{12}]` and `\[[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z-0-9]{12}\]` as well but couldnt find it.

may I know what I am missing here ?

Comment: My Notepad++ complains about `[a-z-0-9]{12}` not being valid, try `[a-z0-9]{12}`

Comment: @sebastian,  how did I miss that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^\[[a-z0-9]{8}-([a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{12}\]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/1/)

Btw, if you need to have '-' in the last block as you have mentioned in your answer [a-z-0-9]{12}. Then you should do it like this : `[a-z0-9-]{12}`

So overall it becomes like this:

```
^\[[a-z0-9]{8}-([a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9-]{12}\]$
```

And it matched in notepad++ as well

Comment: The ID looks like a hex string so you should probably have `a-f` instead of `a-z` (though of course the risk of a false positive is rather small in most data).

Comment: @Ten-Coin, triplee I will change it to `a-f` if the op ask. But I also agree, as hex, it should be a-f

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `-` between `[` and `]` **and between 2 other chars** has special meaning (all chars between).
I think, you are looking for **literal** minus char.
Change the last fragment to either:

- `[a-z\-0-9]` (minus char must be quoted), or
- `[a-z0-9-]` (minus moved to the end).